# Getting a substring from a list of strings

Tags: regex, groovy

So, as part of learning the language, I wanted to check three strings for a certain pattern and return the first match of that pattern only.

My attempt was to use a combination of find and regular expressions to traverse the list:

```
def date = [
  "some string",
  "some other string 11.11.2000",
  "another one 20.10.1990"
].find { title ->
  title =~ /\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/
}
```

This kind of works, leaving the whole string in `date`.

My goal, however, would be to end up with "11.11.2000" in `date`; I assume somehow I should be able to access the capture group, but how?

Comment: This question is a better fit for Stack Overflow.  When you move it, please, for the love of all that is warm and fluffy, *delete it from here.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey It seems I lack the necessary privileges. Do as you want, for I trust your judgment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return a specific value when finding a matching element in a collection (which as in your case might be part of that element), you need to use [findResult](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findResult(groovy.lang.Closure)).

Your code might then look like this

```
def date = [
  "some string",
  "some other string 11.11.2000",
  "another one 20.10.1990"
].findResult { title ->
  def res = title =~ /\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/
  if (res) {
      return res[0]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Extending UnholySheep's answer, you can also do this:

```
assert [
  "some string",
  "some other string 11.11.2000",
  "another one 20.10.1990"
].findResult { title ->
  def matcher = title =~ /\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/
  matcher.find() ? matcher.group() : null
} == '11.11.2000'
```

For all matches, just use `findResults` instead of `findResult`, like this:

```
assert [
  "some string",
  "some other string 11.11.2000",
  "another one 20.10.1990"
].findResults { title ->
  def matcher = title =~ /\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/
  matcher.find() ? matcher.group() : null
} == ['11.11.2000', '20.10.1990']
```